# Error: 'TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'' ' when trying to sort list using lambda function

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I am trying to sort a list of objects based off the following class "listItemString" which contains two variables: a counter variable which identifies how many characters(in ascii num format) and then a list of the ascii values themselves.
The following code is what I currently have

```
import operator

class listItem:
    def __init__(self, counter, char):
        self.counter = counter
        self.char = char
    def __str__(self):
        return "counter: " + str(self.counter) + " char: " + str(self.char)

class listItemString:
    def __init__(self, counter):
        self.counter = counter
        self.internalList = []
    def counterAdding(self, counter2):
        self.newCounter = self.counter + counter2
    def append(self, char):
        self.internalList.append(char)
        self.firstChar = char
    def __str__(self):
        return "counter: " + str(self.counter) + " list: " + str(self.internalList)
initialStr = "HELLOAWORLD"
strList = list(initialStr)
arr = [0] * 150
sortedList = []
items = list()
strItems = list()

for i in range(len(initialStr)):
    arr[ord(strList[i])] = arr[ord(strList[i])] + 1

for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] != 0:
        items.append(listItem(arr[i], i))        

items.sort(key=lambda x: x.counter)

for i in range(len(items)):
    strItems.append(listItemString(items[i].counter))
    strItems[i].append(items[i].char)
    
for i in range(len(strItems)):
    print(strItems[i])

for i in range(1):
    strItems.append(listItemString(strItems[i].counter + strItems[i + 1].counter))
    strItems[len(strItems) - 1].append(strItems[i].internalList)
    strItems[len(strItems) - 1].append(strItems[i + 1].internalList)
for i in range(2):
    strItems.pop(0)


strItems = sorted(strItems, key=lambda element: (element.counter, element.internalList[0]))

for i in range(len(strItems)):
    print("new list " + str(strItems[i]))
```

I'm having issues with the following statement, which is intended to sort the objects first by the counter variable and then by the first element in the list "internalList"

For example the output would be

```
new list counter: 1 list: [69]
new list counter: 1 list: [72]
new list counter: 1 list: [82]
new list counter: 1 list: [87]
new list counter: 2 list: [79]
new list counter: 2 list: [[65], [68]]
new list counter: 3 list: [76]
```

before the sort and it should be

```
new list counter: 1 list: [69]
new list counter: 1 list: [72]
new list counter: 1 list: [82]
new list counter: 1 list: [87]
new list counter: 2 list: [[65], [68]]
new list counter: 2 list: [79]
new list counter: 3 list: [76]
```

after the sort

The problem is with the statement

```
strItems = sorted(strItems, key=lambda element: (element.counter, element.internalList[0]))
```

as it returns the error

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

How can I take the first value of the list within the object and use it to sort the lists by two attributes using the lambda function?

Comment: The error message in the question is not the same as the error in the title.

Comment: Some of your lists are 1-dimensional like `[69]` and `[72]`. But others are 2-dimensional like `[[65], [68]]`. So when you use `element.internalList[0]`, it may be either an integer `69` or a list `[65]`.

Comment: Is there a reason you have `[[65], [68]]` instead of `[65, 69]`?

Comment: I wasn't appending the values of the list, I was appending the entire list, so I need to correct that to only append the values so they're comparable is what I'm realizing now.